# type mismatch with akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route

Tags: scala, akka-http

I've created a http server with akka http as follows:

```
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import com.sweetsoft.LoggerActor.Log
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.adapter._
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http.ServerBinding
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import com.sweetsoft._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.typed.scaladsl.ActorMaterializer

import scala.concurrent.Future

object ProducerActor {

  private val route: Option[ActorRef[ProducerMessage]] => Option[ActorRef[Log]] => Route
  = store => logger =>
    path("producer") {
      post {
        entity(as[ProducerMessage]) { msg =>
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
        }
      }
    }

  def create[A](store: Option[ActorRef[ProducerMessage]], logger: Option[ActorRef[Log]])
               (implicit system: ActorSystem[A])
  : Future[ServerBinding] = {

    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    //Please log
    Http()(system.toUntyped).bindAndHandle(route(store)(logger), getServerIp, getServerPort)
  }

}
```

The compiler complains:

```
[error] /home/developer/scala/plugger/src/main/scala/com/sweetsoft/producer/ProducerActor.scala:35:56: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
[error]     (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
[error]  required: akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest,akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse,Any]
[error]     Http()(system.toUntyped).bindAndHandle(route(store)(logger), getServerIp, getServerPort)
```

Do I forget to import any libraries?

Comment: What akka version is this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.1.9/routing-dsl/routes.html):

> Using `Route.handlerFlow` or `Route.asyncHandler` a `Route` can be lifted into a handler `Flow` or async handler function to be used with a `bindAndHandleXXX` call from the Core Server API.
>
> Note: There is also an implicit conversion from `Route` to `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Unit]` defined in the `RouteResult` companion, which relies on `Route.handlerFlow`.

Therefore, you have at least three options:

1. Call `Route.handlerFlow`:

```
...bindAndHandle(Route.handlerFlow(route(store)(logger)), ...)
```

2. Import the methods in the `Route` companion object and do the same as above, except now you can drop the explicit reference to the `Route` object:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route._

...bindAndHandle(handlerFlow(route(store)(logger)), ...)
```

3. Import `akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult._`:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult._

...bindAndHandle(route(store)(logger), ...)
```

Comment: I've tried with the third option and the compiler still complain `type mismatch`. I also tried with 1 and 2 but do not know, how to fill all settings option.

Comment: What was missing is this two statemaents `private implicit val untyped = system.toUntyped;
  private implicit val dispatcher = untyped.dispatcher`.